# Getting import error in Python 2.7 when tried with

Tags: python, xlwt

I need to import classes from `xlwt` module, accordingly I have tried getting error. Why so?
Can you guide me here?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Matty>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from xlwt import easyxf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named xlwt
>>> from xlwt import Workbook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named xlwt
>>>
```

**EDIT**

```
C:\Users\matt>easy_install xlwt
Searching for xlwt
Best match: xlwt 0.7.4
Processing xlwt-0.7.4-py2.7.egg
Adding xlwt 0.7.4 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.4-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for xlwt
Finished processing dependencies for xlwt

C:\Users\matt>
```

**EDIT1**

**As per the comments from  @Ab it works.**

***But why I need to import sys ?***

```
C:\Users\matt>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\beautifulsoup4-4.1.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Py
thon27\\lib\\site-packages\\selenium-2.28.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site
-packages\\xlwt-0.7.4-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Py
thon27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27
\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
>>> from xlwt import easyxf
>>> from xlwt import Workbook
>>> from xlwt import *
>>>
```

Comment: Have you installed the `xlwt` module?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed it?

Comment: Yes I have installed it,using `easy_install xlwt`.

Comment: What was the output of `easy_install xlwt`?

Comment: How to check the that, I am using python2.7. But with the same I also install `selenium` , `bs4` all are working fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `import sys ; sys.path` and see if `c:\python27\lib\site-packages\` is in your path list. If it is, then again try run `from xlwt import easyxf`

Comment: `import sys` is needed to load and run sys.path (to check your PYTHONPATH)

Comment: when I am importing from `selenium,bs4` then i didn't use `import sys`. but for `xlrd`,`xlwt` why I need to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You clearly don't have `xlwt` installed, or Python doesn't know that you do.

Try running `pip install xlwt`.

You can also look to see where physically the code for `xlwt` is, and then add that file directory to your `PYTHONPATH` so that Python will know to look there for the module.

This could be because you're running your code from a `virtualenv` that does not have `xlwt` installed.

Comment: I am not using `virtualenv`.